# Two Windows servers but AJAX only works on one

Tags: .net, ajax, iis, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a development server and a production server. I created a very simple page to test the AJAX extensions. AJAX works fine on the dev server, but doesn't work on production.

- The aspx and aspx.vb pages are identical on both servers.
- The web.config files are identical on both servers.
- The AjaxControlToolkit.dll file is the same and is in the bin directory on both servers.
- The AjaxControlToolkit.dll version is 3.0.11119.0.

What are the possible causes?

Is there a .Net function or method that will return a meaningful value that will tell me if AJAX is installed and what versions are registered in the GAC?

Comment: It simply doesn't work or there are some errors in the browser?

Comment: I just doesn't work at all. For example, the code below prevents non-numeric characters from being entered into the textbox. Works fine on development. On production, you can enter anything you want, as if AJAX is not present at all.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <ajaxToolKit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtUnitPrice_FilteredTextBoxExtender" 
                        runat="server" enabled="True"  FilterType="Numbers"
                        TargetControlID="txtUnitPrice"/>              
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUnitPrice" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtUnitPrice" ErrorMessage="unit price" 
                        ValidationGroup="VS1">*
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: That's strange. Different setting on IIS virtual directories perhaps?

Comment: I don't have access to the server to be able to tell, but that would be my guess. Is there any code that I could run that would return virtual directory settings and so forth?

Comment: Mmm..can't you ask the team who manage the server?

Comment: production: v4.0.30319.34237,  v3.5.0.0, v1.0.61025.0  

development: v4.0.30318.1024, v3.5.0.0, v1.0.61025.0